Vue JS how to properly load and refresh Vue app with Apollo and Auth0 JWT tokens
In main.js we have the below code to load the Vue app with Apollo and Auth0. This works but has always felt hacky and is now running into an issue where if the JWT token expires the user gets errors until they refresh the page and main.js is re-run.
...

import { createApp, provide, h } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error'
import { logErrorMessages } from '@vue/apollo-util'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';
import { split } from 'apollo-link'
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

...

const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-token')

let headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
if(token){
  headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
}

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URI,
  headers: headers
})

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: import.meta.env.VITE_API_WS,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    inactivityTimeout: 30000,
    lazy: true,
    connectionParams: {
      headers: headers
    }
  },
})

const errorLink = onError(error => {
  logErrorMessages(error)
})

const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query)
    return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
  },
  errorLink.concat(wsLink),
  errorLink.concat(httpLink)
)

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true,
})

const app = createApp({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },
  render: () => h(App),
})

const auth0 = createAuth0({
  domain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
  audience: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_AUDIENCE
})

app.use(auth0)

...

app.mount('#app')

Essentially the issue is we need both Auth0 and Apollo clients for creating and launching the app within main.js. However the ApolloClient HTTP and WS links need the JWT token for their headers, but Auth0 method getAccessTokenSilently for getting the token can only be run from within the Vue app.
So currently when a page loads we run the following code from within the onMount of a global Vue component. This will store the token and reload main.js if a new token is detected which will in turn puts the token into the ApolloClient. As mentioned above this feels hacky and causes errors on page actions if the token has expired, until the user reloads the page manually.
async function storeAccessToken(){
  let prevToken = localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
  let accessToken = await auth0.getAccessTokenSilently()
  localStorage.setItem("auth-token", accessToken)
  let didLogin = prevToken == null && accessToken != null
  if(didLogin){
    location.reload()
  } else if(accessToken == null){
    localStorage.clear()
    router.push({ path: '/' })
    alert('You have been logged out')
  }
}

We are looking at fixing by catching the token expired error and forcing a page reload but this is not ideal, ideally we would silently fetch a new token, add it to the ApolloClient link headers, and try again.
Is it possible to update the ApolloClient from within the Vue app code? (Instead of reloading the page to re-run main.js)
Otherwise if there is a better or accepted way to solve the Apollo / Auth0 issue above this would be great to know.
Here are some links we used when developing this setup:
https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/vue/apollo-client/
https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/vue/basic-authentication#call-a-protected-api-from-vue-js
